# Web Part problem (Content Query), "Sorry, Something went Wrong"

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, content-query-web-part

I'm trying to correct a broken web part that's not pointing to the correct list (Content Query Web Part).  However, when I click to edit, I get the "Sorry, something went wrong"...File Not Found.  There's a link to "Web Parts Maintenance Page".  When I click on it, I see my Content by Query type but not sure where to from there.  The only options I have are links: Close, Reset, Delete, Go Back to Web Part Page, or Switch to Personal View.  Is there a way to correct this web part from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the content query web part and readd the content query web part.

Comment: Should I view or inspect the source to see what the property settings are for that web part?  Or just put it up adjust as i go?  The format looks different than the views in the actual lists.